# Delphi 2D. Статическое изменение рисунка

Tags: java, delphi, graphics

Необходимо сделать мнемосхему на Delphi. Делал подобные на Java. Собственно создавал объекты, в них хранил данные расположения, цвет и другие параметры. Перерисовывал их методом repaint() на JPanel. Подскажите как сделать подобное на Delphi?

**UPDATE**

К примеру я рисую прямоугольник

```
Form1.Canvas.Rectangle(45, 20, 71, 70);
```

При этом задав до этого его свойства.
Далее после некоторых событий мне необходимо его изменить. (цвет координаты и т.д.)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: @Kromster так понятнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, все рисуется на канву TBitmap созданного в памяти, а потом он за 1 вызов рисуется на видимую канву (например `Form1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bitmap);`). Соответственно при изменении чего-то - все стирается и рисуется заново.

Другой вариант, разместить на форме всякие TShape и TImage и управлять их расположением и свойствами.

Answer (score 0):

Зарисовываете прямоугольник по старым координатам цветом фона, потом рисуете новый по новым координатам и/или новым цветом. Ну или перерисовывать всю картинку целиком каждый раз при изменении свойств объектов.